# How to add new columns from a list to an existing dataframe in polars?

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

I'd like to add new empty columns (elements of mylist) to an existing dataframe.
This code does it:

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3]})
mylist = [f'col{i}' for i in range(1,4)]
data = [[''] for i in range(1,len(mylist)+1)]

df.join(pl.DataFrame(data=data,schema=mylist),
        how='cross')
```

But is there a more polars way to do this? Something using .with_columns() or pl.any()? So that I do not have to create a new dataframe and join it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be looking for [`pl.lit()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.lit.html#polars.lit) which allows you to create an "expression" from a literal value.

You can then use `.alias()` to choose the name.

```py
df.with_columns(pl.lit('').alias(col) for col in mylist)
```

```py
shape: (3, 4)
┌─────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ a   ┆ col1 ┆ col2 ┆ col3 │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  │
╞═════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆      ┆      ┆      │
│ 2   ┆      ┆      ┆      │
│ 3   ┆      ┆      ┆      │
└─────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

`map()` could also be used instead of a comprehension.

```py
df.with_columns(map(pl.lit('').alias, mylist))
```

Comment: also dict comprehension with unpacking `df.with_columns(**{col:pl.lit('') for col in mylist})`

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, I think you just need to make sure the data is in an array/series structure:

```
arr = np.random.randint(0,10,(5,5))
df = pl.DataFrame(arr)
df.with_columns(new_col=np.array([i for i in range(5)]))
```

Produces:

```
column_0    column_1    column_2    column_3    column_4    new_col
i64 i64 i64 i64 i64 i64
3   6   8   6   2   0
9   2   1   0   3   1
5   9   8   1   4   2
0   8   6   3   9   3
4   9   0   1   1   4
```

The relevant [documentation page](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.with_columns.html#polars.DataFrame.with_columns) has a few examples of the different ways you can structure it, but they are all of data already in some polars format.

Comment: The starting point is that you have a dataframe and a list containing new field names. From this starting point, how would you do it your way?